# as3, Function in imported Class is not being called . Type Error: Error #1006

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, typeerror

Please see the following code.

> **mainClass.as**

```
package
{
    import mfClass.CarSelector;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class MainClass extends MovieClip
    {
        private var carSel:CarSelector;
        public function MainClass()
        {
            show_selector();
        }
        private function show_selector():void
        {
            carSel = new CarSelector();
            carSel.sel_Fun();
        }
    }
}
```

> **CarSelector.as** ... this file is in one next folder "mfClass".

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class CarSelector extends MovieClip {
        public function CarSelector() {
            this.x = 200;
            this.y = 50;
        }
        public function sel_Fun():void
        {
            trace("array");
        }
    }

}
```

Now.. when i run this in flash. i get this message.. in output.

```
TypeError: Error #1006: sel_Fun is not a function.
    at MainClass/show_selector()
    at MainClass()
```

Can somebody please help me.. what is the reason.. i've been facing this for 2 nights.. this is cropped class.. i removed and re-write.. but couldn't get the solution..

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
package mfClass
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class CarSelector extends MovieClip {
```

if it's in the 'mfClass' folder

Comment: www0z0k.. thanks for tip.. i tried like that... but that didn't work...

That's why i put mfClass folder's path in class paths..